# RewriteRule to handle one domain two folders to two domains no folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to create rewrite rules to handle some specific website redirections:

I would like domain**1**.ca/**folder1**/xyz to go to domain**2**.ca/xyz and domain**1**.ca/**folder2**/xyz to go to domain**3**.ca/xyz

Right now my attempts are as following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.ca$
RewriteRule ^(\/folder1\/)(.*)$ "https://domain2.ca/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.ca$
RewriteRule ^(\/folder2\/)(.*)$ "https://domain3.ca/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :) Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of problems with your existsing rules:

- In `.htaccess` the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash. So, the URL-path starts `folder1/xyz`, not `/folder1/xyz`.
- You are unnecessarily capturing "folder1" in the first parenthesised subpattern and using this in the *substitution* string (ie. `$1`). You should be using `$2`, or don't capture the first path segment.

The directives could also be tidied up a bit (eg. no need to backslash-escape slashes in the regex and the *conditions* can be combined).

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.ca [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*) https://domain2.ca/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.ca [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder2/(.*) https://domain3.ca/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Additional notes:

- The end-of-string anchor (`$`) following `(.*)$` in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is not required since regex is greedy by default.
- You only need to surround the argument in double quotes if it contains *spaces*.
- I removed the end-of-string anchor (`$`) from the end of the *CondPattern* to also match fully qualified domain names that end in a dot.
- I added the `NC` flag to the condition. It's technically possible that some bots can send a mixed/uppercase `Host` header.

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite... works perfectly. And I appreciate the additional notes.